# How to copy image name from firebase storage to firebase database? Javascript and Java

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can already save the image to the firebase storage named as uid of the current user. Is there any way I can copy the image name  from firebase storage, to my firebase database? Because I want to put the uploaded image inside my marker in google maps activity. I'll do this in my google maps activity in android using java and my google maps in my web using javascript.

Edit:
Is it possible to do a query in my firebase storage just like in firebase database so that I can easily get the file name and save it in my `Users`/`UID`/`image_found/HERE` node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the storage link from Firebase Storage, not sure what you're asking. You can also set your the desired name for your image.

If you're asking how you can do this, then you can find all the answers in this piece of code:

```java
private void uploadFile(Bitmap bitmap) {

        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        final StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();

         // this is how you set your desired name for the image
        final StorageReference ImagesRef = storageRef.child("images/"+mAu.getCurrentUser().getUid()+".jpg");


        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
        final UploadTask uploadTask = ImagesRef.putBytes(data);

        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.i("whatTheFuck:",exception.toString());
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
               // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.

                Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.i("problem", task.getException().toString());
                        }

                        return ImagesRef.getDownloadUrl(); 
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();

                            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mAu.getCurrentUser().getUid());


                            Log.i("seeThisUri", downloadUri.toString());// This is the link or name you should use to save or set the image

                            ref.child("imageURL").setValue(downloadUri.toString());


                        } else {
                            Log.i("wentWrong","downloadUri failure");
                        }
                    }
                });
             }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Hello sir, can I get a kotlin implementation of this? I forgot that the image processing on my project is in kotlin.

Comment: You can convert Java code to Kotlin in android studio itself, for more details, read this: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjGk83q34DfAhVIOBoKHRsdAWsQFjACegQIBhAL&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnilsmagnus.github.io%2Fpost%2Fandroid-annotations-kotlin%2F&usg=AOvVaw10i31pTVUcFYmY3_hK-eXO

Comment: my friend did this and the result is `com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@6cfd338`

Comment: It can't be, this is a tried and tested code which I have used in 2 of my apps. Please check the code, to see if you're using the same `downloadUri.toString()` or not.

Comment: okay sir, I will triple check it. Thanks again!